# How to init some functions in RESTful web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am utterly new to java web services and currently writing a RESTful web service in java. I want to call a method when the web service is deploying in order to initialize some values. How can I achieve this?..

I am using Axis2 as my deployment engine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to specify what framework you are using.

Comment: I am using axis2. I've updated the question.

Comment: Could you do your init in a default constructor?

Comment: You mean the "ServiceClass" constructor right?.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a listener [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

When you will launch your application server, the "contextInitialized" method will be called and exactly do what you want like initialize a static configuration class ; depending on what you want to achieve.

EDIT : 
You'll need to declare the listener into your web.xml like this :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>full.classpath.to.MyServletContextListenerImpl</listener-class>
</listener>
```

As an exemple, I use a listener in order to initialize my custom PoolManager which is a singleton.

I hope it can help you !

Comment: I am using axis2. So can I use that?

Comment: ServletContextListener is part of the Java EE jdk so you can use it in addition to any other framework.

Comment: I tried to implement the interface but I'm unable to do it. Do I need any library to impelment the class??

Comment: No, it's part of Java EE as mentioned above ; the full path is "javax.servlet.ServletContextListener". What's the error message ?

Comment: I am not using servlets. just the axis2 component. Not a .war archive it's a .aar archive. Which means I can't use servlets right?. (I am deploying it in axis2)

Comment: It seems it was possible with Axis but no more in Axis 2. Sorry for that fail trail. I let anybody more relevant to help you. Good luck.